# Mapping JSON key values to Core Data attributes in RestKit 0.20.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, restkit, restkit-0.20

Given this JSON:

```
{ 
    "company": "Big Inc."
    "products": [
        {
            "category": "",
            "daily_sales": {
                "2013-04-13": 23
                "2013-05-27": 67
                "2013-05-28": 89
            }
        },
        {
            "category": "",
            "daily_sales": {
                "2013-04-13": 23
                "2013-05-27": 67
                "2013-05-28": 89
            }
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

I want to flatten it and save it in objects like this:

- SALE

  - company (string)
  - category (string)
  - date (date)
  - sales (int)

So the JSON example above would generate 6 objects.

**How do I configure the mapping in RestKit to include the key (the date) as a mapped value into the new object?**

Comment: A single object to hold those parts? You can't, because the JSON holds an array, how would you map all the array contents to a single object? Or am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: I want to save it de-normalized and one object for each date - "So the JSON example above would generate 6 objects."

Comment: RestKit can't do that for you automatically I think. You'd need to either manipulate the data before it is mapped or map the data into another object and then post-process it.

Comment: Maybe you're right. But it doesn't seem to be a nice way to hook into the mapping chain when using RKObjectManager. You need a RKObjectRequestOperation to be able to set the `willMapDeserializedResponseBlock` block. I guess I need to copy the `getObjectsAtPathForRelationship...` and `getObjectsAtPathForRouteNamed` methods in RKObjectManager to set that block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to do this with RestKit mapping (as of 0.20.1).

You can modify the response to make it RestKit-friendly. I've made a category on RKObjectManager to easily provide a block to modify the response:

https://gist.github.com/gunnarblom/5677324